# Determening the best estimator for the mean value.

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, means

You have two testing methods A and B. Let X equal the measured values with method A and Y equal the measured values with method B. X and Y are both normally distributed and have a mean value of  μ. Assume that the variance for X is $0.2^2$ and the variance for Y is $0.1^2$. Of the following suggestions, what is the best estimation for μ?

$$Y$$
$${{1}/{2}}X + {{1}/{2}}Y$$
$${{1}/{5}}X + {{4}/{5}}Y$$

I'm really stuck at this problem, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you find the expected value of each of the estimators? What about their variances?

Comment: @soakley Isn't the expected value what I'm trying to find the expression for?

Comment: That's just the first part. For example, for the second estimator, its expectation is $E[{{X} \over {2}}+{{Y} \over {2}}] = {{1} \over {2}} E[X] +{{1} \over {2}} E[Y] = {{\mu} \over {2}}+{{\mu} \over {2}}=\mu.$ Now can you complete it for the others and then move to the variance of the estimators?